# How to stop terminating a script by ctrl+c in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How can I stop Ctrl+C terminating a script in the Bourne Again shell (Bash)? What can I do so that a bash script will not stop when Ctrl+C is pressed?

Comment: Although you *can* do it, I would hate to have a script block CTRL-C.  This would force me to kill my session if I wanted the script to end.  Bad practice IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> sends the `INT` ("interrupt") signal to the foreground process of the shell.  This signal can be ignored.

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap '' INT   # ignore INT
sleep 100
```

The script may still be interrupted by e.g. the `TERM` signal (and a handful of others), which is the signal sent by default by `kill`. In an interactive `bash` session you may also suspend the process with <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> and then kill it with `kill %+` (`%+` corresponds to "the current job" which will be the script if you just suspended it).  You may ignore the `TERM` signal in the same way as you ignore the `INT` signal.

If you just want to ignore the `INT` signal for a section of your script, you may later reinstate the default behaviour with

```
trap - INT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trap` for that.

```
$ trap --help
```

https://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/misc/trapping-ctrl-c-in-bash